# copy issue source to destination single quote

Tags: shell, unix

I have the below content in a inputfile `BONUS.PS,$DIR/BONUS.PSB`

Below is the code.

```
DIR=/home/sample
for i in `cat inputfile`
do
source=`echo $line|awk -F, '{print $1}'|tr -d "'"`
destination=`echo $line|awk -F, '{print $2}'|tr -d "'"`
echo $source $destination
cp -v $source $destination
done
```

I could not achieve the copy to work here. In the source I get the value as `BONUS.PS`, in the destination I get the value as `'$DIR/BONUS.PSB'`   (single quote). Because of the single quote I could not perform the copy from source to destination.

Comment: I have the below content in a inputfile. BONUS.PS,$DIR/BONUS.PSB
Below is the code. DIR=/home/sample for i in cat inputfile do source=echo $line|awk -F, '{print $1}'|tr -d "'"destination=echo $line|awk -F, '{print $2}'|tr -d "'"echo $source $destination cp -v $source $destination done
I could achieve the copy to work here. In source i get the value as BONUS.PS In destination i get the value as '$DIR/BONUS.PSB' (single quote) Because of the single quote I could perform the copy from source to destination.

Comment: `newdest=$(eval "echo $destination")` would fix the problem. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the indirect referencing problem.

As mentioned [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html), how to build "dynamic" variable names and evaluate their contents. This can be useful when sourcing configuration files.

```
#!/bin/bash
# This could be "sourced" from a separate file.

isdnMyProviderRemoteNet=172.16.0.100
isdnYourProviderRemoteNet=10.0.0.10
isdnOnlineService="MyProvider"

remoteNet=$(eval "echo \$$(echo isdn${isdnOnlineService}RemoteNet)")
remoteNet=$(eval "echo \$$(echo isdnMyProviderRemoteNet)")
remoteNet=$(eval "echo \$isdnMyProviderRemoteNet")
remoteNet=$(eval "echo $isdnMyProviderRemoteNet")

echo "$remoteNet"    # 172.16.0.100
```

To address your concern,

You may need to change your script to below.

I changed the use of `line` and referenced as `i`, removed backticks, removed `tr`

```
DIR=/home/sample
for i in $(cat inputfile)
do
source=$(echo $i|awk -F, '{print $1}')
destination=$(echo $i|awk -F, '{print $2}')

newdest=$(eval "echo $destination")
echo "$source"
echo "$newdest"

cp -v $source $newdest
done
```

I did a small test and it worked fine.